# Trouble finding the boundaries of the intersection of 3 curves

Tags: calculus, integration, area

I have the following question here:

> Find the area of the region in the first quadrant that is bounded by the following curves:
> $$y=x-\frac{x^2}{4},y=\frac{4}{x^2} \text{ and } y=x^3+3x.$$

Can I do this intutively without plotting? I mean, I could plot it and do this but there has to be a nicer way.

[image]

The plot looks something like this. So do I just subtract the green and red curves, integrate that from $0$ to $1$ and then subtract the blue and red curves from $1$ to $2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you got it right. But you forgot to mention that you need to add the two parts to get the total area. Call the green function $y = x^3+3x$, the red function $y = x - \dfrac{x^2}{4}$, and the blue function $y = \dfrac{4}{x^2}$, then you can split the area into two areas **A** and **B** where **A** $ = \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 (\text{green function} - \text{red function}) dx$, and **B** $= \displaystyle \int_{1}^2 (\text{blue function} - \text{red function}) dx$, and your area $=$ **A + B**. Can you continue?

Comment: Yeah I know I have to add it. I got it. It's 29/12. Thank you :) .

Comment: You are welcome @FutureMathperson.

Answer (score 2):

Plotting is the best way. With two functions, you could simply find the intersections and see which function is greater at each interval, and thus find the bounded region. But for three or more functions, this method would be very inefficient.

And yes your approach to calculating the area is correct.

Comment: Darn. Fair enough I guess. Thanks!